# Jquery removing class of span object without passing the Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input tag before which I have a span tag.

```
<li>
<span class="class1 class2" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"></span>
<input id="in1" class="inputclass" type="checkbox" name="in1">
<label for="in1">text here</label>
</li>
<li>
<span class="class1 class2" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"></span> 
<input id="in2" class="inputclass" type="checkbox" name="in2">
<label for="in2">text2 here</label>
</li>
```

I need to remove the class2 from the 2nd span tag above when checkbox i.e in1 is checked.
How can I do that?

Also there are many input and span tags. 
please help.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean before the input tag? is it wrapped, or is it just before input tag in the page ?

Comment: karthikr: No its not. just a simple code.

Comment: Muhammad Ramahy:provided the code snippet. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$('.inputclass:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this)
        .parent() // li tag
        .next() // adjacent li tag
        .children('span')
        .toggleClass('class2', !this.checked);
});
```

Upon change, it finds the `<span>` element inside the next `<li`> and toggles the `.class2` class based on whether it's clicked or not using `.toggleClass()`.

If select boxes are dynamically added to the document you could use event delegation like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputclass:checkbox', function() { ... });
```

Change `document` to an element that's the closest ancestor of all your check boxes where possible.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the code but there are cases where 'onclick' of above check box the class2 of below span should change which mean: consider span1 input1 span2 input2 then onclick of input1 span2 should change its class.

Comment: @Grish Your question states that the span comes before the input box; is there a rule that determines where the span is?

Comment: yes. Basically i just want to change the class of span2 tag which is below the input1 tag but there comes more problem because each input and span tags are in <li> like this `<li><span class="class1 class2" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"></span>
<input id="in1" class="inputclass" type="checkbox" name="in1"><label for="in1">text here</label></li><li>.....`.

Comment: @Grish Why don't you update the question based on the current set of answers to clear a few things up. At this point the question can't be unambiguously answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#in1").change(
  function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).prev().removeClass("class2");
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".inputclass").change(
  function() {
    if (!($(this).is(":checked"))) {
      $(this).parent().childern(".class2").removeClass("class2");
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li input:checkbox").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next().find('span').removeClass('class2');
});
```